# Wordpress - the_content doens't give p tags back

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using a piece of code that returns all of my pages on 1 page (custom wordpress theme). The code works perfectly, but I can't manage to output the pages with any p tags or formatting.

```
$pages = get_pages(); 

foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content); 
    $title = $page_data->post_title; 
    echo $content; 
}
```

I've read that you can use get_the_content, but I don't see how I can implemented this in my loop.

Thanks

G.

Comment: Hi. You should try asking at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/, they are experts in these matters. Good luck.

Comment: Have a look for this code -> `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );` . It will be removing the formatting. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

Answer (score 3):

Try using wpautop function.

```
echo wpautop($content);
```