# Get the_content by ID and preserve the <p>-tag in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get the content of a custom post type by an ID an return it in a shortcode.

I found multiple ways to do that. But all of them remove the `<p>`-tags from the content.

Here is what I've tried:

```
// Get the ID from a meta field
$post_id        = $id;


// Method 1
$banner_content = get_post($post_id);
$content = $banner_content->post_content;


// Method 2
$content = apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $post_id));


// Method 3
$content_post = get_post($post_id);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);


// Method 4
$content = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);


// Output in a shortcode
return '<div>'.$content.'</div>';
```

Is there a way to preserve the `<p>`-tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: [Wordpress - the_content doens't give p tags back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546589/wordpress-the-content-doenst-give-p-tags-back)

For my example, this works:

```
return '<div>'.wpautop($content).'</div>';
```